# How to do calculation between px and % in sass/scss

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to do calculation between px and % :

```
$font-size-h1: 50px !default;   //variable name

line-height: $font-size-h1*1.15%;
```

What I am getting on compiling scss to css:-

> Error: 57.5%*px isn't a valid CSS value.

I wanted to eliminate px from output i.e : 57.5%

Comment: Why can't you change 1.15% to `0.0115px` maybe a px value can only be multiplied to a px. Try doing `$font-size-h1*percentage(1.15)`

Comment: it is still showing same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the px unit by dividing it by `1px`.

```
line-height: ($font-size-h1/1px) * 1.15%;
```

Basically: `50px / 1px = 50`.

Comment: Thanks @graygilmore :)